# Sharepoint 2010 - disable web analytic on site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics

We are facing a performance issues on our environment, that is why we want to disable Sharepoint Web Analytics on sites. The main target is to disable web analytics only on specified site collections, but the farm feature and service should stay enabled. 
Is there any way we can disable site analytics on site collection? By disabling I mean, site shouldn't be processed by service application. 
I found similar topics, but all of them describes how to disable web analytics on farm, and we want to cut only specified sites.

Answer (score 0):

First you can Find all activated Web Analytics Features in your Farm using PowerShell command & find how many are features available for Farm, for CA & for Site Collections. You need to loop through all web applications and site collections & get appropriate features to disable them.

Please follow this link to resolve your problem.

[Find all activated Web Analytics Features](http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2014/10/01/find-all-activated-web-analytics-features)

You need to modify the last PowerShell commands to disable the feature after getting it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already saw this article and we consider disabling all web analytics features with Site scope. But I have doubts if this action will be enough, after disabling every feature on site related to web analytics (there is 6 features as I remember), will stop processing of the site by web analytics? If it won't engage any report process, this solution suits us.

Comment: it will stop processing the Web Analytic & stop generating the report for the particular site.